# Android Java - can't catch exception

Tags: java, android, exception

This is my function:

```
void send() throws SocketException
{
    ....

    socket.setSoTimeout(1000);

    ....
}
```

I use it in other function:

```
try
    {
        send();
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Log.i("Timeout", "Exception");
    }
```

but the catch seems not to work, no logs. I am 100% sure that timeout occurs (W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketTimeoutException). I was trying also with Throwable instead of SocketException but it didn't help.

Comment: A `SocketTimeoutException` is not a `SocketException`.

Answer (score 1):

From 30 seconds on Google: A `SocketTimeoutException` is not a `SocketException`.

Try catching a `SocketTimeoutException` instead.

Comment: I have error on the socket.setSoTimeout: Error:(82, 28) error: unreported exception SocketException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. I changed send() to throws SocketTimeoutException

Comment: You know you can catch 2 types of exceptions?